# Merge similar records in access

Tags: ms-access, merge

I have a table to which new records will be added from a spreadsheet in bulk using Access's import function. Sometimes, the new records will be refer to the same person and I would like to merge them.

Please could someone explain to me how to do this?
(I am an Access novice but have some experience with Excel and Excel vba)

The data is structured like this:

```
Key    First Name   Last Name    Date Attended    Email Address    Contactable?

1      Joe          Bloggs       1/1/2001         j@blogs.com      True

2      Joe          Bloggs       9/10/2004        j@blogs.com      False
```

Ideally, it would be merged such that:

- the email address must be the same
- the first and last names must be the same
- the most recent 'contactable' field is retained
- dates attended are all stored (ie several values in this field for each record).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: But what **truly, uniquely** identifies these people? Email Address? What if it's a BS email address? Or are they validated?

Comment: The data is collected by people voluntarily entering their details into a google form. You are right, there is no way of guaranteeing that someone is honest, however, if someone wishes to be contacted, it is reasonable to assume they also entered a valid email. Without becoming intrusive, I cannot think of another way of identifying people other then, perhaps, their date of birth? It would not change that I would need to merge details across multiple records which is my main goal.